# How to debug loading of wrong Maven plugin

Tags: maven

In build section of my effective pom there is a Maven plugin that I don't want to use (it was used before, but now I want to remove it).
I removed this plugin from every parent of my project, but is is still applied.

How do I find out where this plugin declaration come from?

UPDATE:
It turns out this plugin was an implicit dependency of another one. It was not declared as such, but referenced from plugin's components.XML leading to runtime dependency injection. The problem was found by pure luck. I think the question is still relevant - it should be possible to find implicit plugin dependencies without wasting a day or two.

Comment: What kind of plugin are you talking about? How does you pom file look like?

Answer (score 0):

Have you run

```
mvn install
```

on the parent pom when you deleted the plugin from there?

When you run mvn from submodule it actually looks into your local repository for parent/siblings modules (jars, poms), not to filesystem (compared to maven using the result of the build when you run whole parent project build with submodules).

If it doesn't help, have a look if it's not coming from super pom. You can see super pom on maven website:

http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.5/maven-model-builder/super-pom.html